# Adding Custom Currency in Magento 2.1.13 Store?

Tags: magento-2.1

I want to add Custom currency option as (points) in my store like  Rupees,dollars and euros etc. Is there any module for this ??.  Can any one help to write the code for this ? 
ThankYou.

Answer (score 0):

First you need to select a currency from 
 store-configuration then in General tab -> Currency setup, from there select it and save

Now from Store->Currency Symbols, add a symbol or name for it

then Store ->Currency Rates define the rate of that currency per 1 unit and save

Answer (score 0):

You can select multiple currenct for your store from admin.

Goto **Stores -> Configuration** then click on Currency Setup then you will get the below screen.
[image]

You can select multiple currency from Allow Currencies. Also you can define the default currency from here as well.

If you want to define different rate for different currencies then you need to goto **Stores -> Currency Rates**

And if you want to change the currency symbol for your currencies then goto **Stores -> Currency Symbols**